# Spring Oauth2 returns 401 Unauthorized error with spring boot 2.0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am trying to implement SSO with spring oauth2. For the spring 1.5.x, it works fine. However once i upgrade the oauth server app to spring boot  2.2.3.RELEASE, i even cannot go to login form. 
Going to "http://localhost:8082/" redirect "http://localhost:8080/sso-server/oauth/authorize?client_id=foo&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8082/login&response_type=code&state=9EOxmA" and returns error message

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Full authentication is required to access this resource"
}
```

Server app

```
SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer
public class SsoServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SsoServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        @Bean
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin().and().httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("foo")
                    .secret("bar")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                    .scopes("user_info")
                    .autoApprove(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer
                    .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                    .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
            oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
    }
}
```

Client app

```
package com.shekhargulati.app1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.EnableOAuth2Sso;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@RestController
public class App1Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

UserController

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user/me")
    public Principal user(Principal principal) {
        return principal;
    }
}
```

client application.properities

```
server:
    port: 8082
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: foo
      clientSecret: bar
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/sso-server/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/sso-server/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:8080/sso-server/user/me
```

server application.properties file

```
server.port=8080
server.context-path=/sso-server
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shekhargulati</groupId>
    <artifactId>sso-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>sso-server</name>
    <description>SSO Server</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Runtime, com.sun.xml.bind module -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-oauth2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

client app pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shekhargulati</groupId>
    <artifactId>app1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>app1</name>
    <description>App1</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth.boot/spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->

    </dependencies>



    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You didn't permit access to your login page. You have to allow anonymous access for your login page.

Comment: Thank you! It works as i added authentication filter on the clientg app. However i add the success handler configuration on the server side it redirect me to the server auth/login page with 403 authentication error. Is there any additional configuration i am missing ?

Comment: @Component
public class TestHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
            response.sendRedirect("localhost:8082/tt");
        }
    }
}

Comment: On the server side
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login","/login2","/login/process", "/oauth/authorize")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll();
        ;
    }